# vb.net Get PrivateMemorySize64 and process id sort by memory size

Tags: vb.net

I've got the following:

```
Dim plist() As Process = Process.GetProcesses()

    For Each prs As Process In plist

        ListBox1.Items.Add(prs.ProcessName + "   (" + (prs.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024000).ToString() + " MB)")
```

But id really like to get it to list it by memory size if possible? If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated

Comment: If your code works and lists all the processes you are interested in. Then you could simply use a bubble sort and sort the list based on the memory size.

Comment: Thanks Zaf, Im quite net to vb.net how would I go about applying a bubble sort on this ? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic sample, you will have to customise it to your needs.

```
Public Class Form1
'
Dim pList() As Process = Nothing
'
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '
    Dim pItem As Process = Nothing
    Dim pCounter As Integer = Nothing
    '
    pList = Process.GetProcesses()
    For pCounter = 0 To pList.Count - 1
        pItem = pList(pCounter)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(pItem.ProcessName + "   (" + (pItem.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024000).ToString() + " MB)")        '
    Next
    'sort list
    SortProcessList()
    '
End Sub
'
Sub SortProcessList()
    '
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim pTmp As Process
    '
    'sort list based on lowest usage first
    For i = 0 To pList.Count - 2
        For j = i + 1 To pList.Count - 1
            If pList(i).PrivateMemorySize64 > pList(j).PrivateMemorySize64 Then
                pTmp = pList(i)
                pList(i) = pList(j)
                pList(j) = pTmp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    ReloadSortedList()
    '
End Sub

Sub ReloadSortedList()
    '
    Dim pItem As Process = Nothing
    Dim pCounter As Integer = Nothing
    '
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For pCounter = 0 To pList.Count - 1
        pItem = pList(pCounter)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(pItem.ProcessName + "   (" + (pItem.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024000).ToString() + " MB)")        '
    Next
    'tidy up
    pItem = Nothing
    pCounter = Nothing
    '
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Note that the LIST of processes is SORTED and not the items in the LISTBOX, that is why we reloaded the LISTBOX from the Processes list. You could of course simply sort the LISTBOX contents instead of the PROCESSES LIST